# Orientdb transaction - cannot lock record

Tags: orientdb, orientjs

I'm receiving an error when trying to complete a transaction using orientdb with orientjs. Here is the error:

```
2015-10-21 15:48:33:868 FINE  [node1442848110394] Distributed transaction: locked record #12:19 in database 'MyDb' owned by server 'node1442848110394' [OHazelcastDistributedDatabase]
2015-10-21 15:48:33:868 FINE  [node1442848110394] Distributed transaction: cannot lock record #12:19 in database 'MyDb' owned by server 'node1442848110394' [OHazelcastDistributedDatabase]
2015-10-21 15:48:33:868 FINE  [node1442848110394] Distributed transaction: unlocked record #12:19 in database 'MyDb' [OHazelcastDistributedDatabase]
2015-10-21 15:48:33:869 FINE  [node1442848110394] sending back response 'com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.task.ODistributedRecordLockedException' to request 28 (tx) [ODistributedWorker]Error on transaction commit
com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.task.ODistributedRecordLockedException
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.task.OTxTask.execute(OTxTask.java:104)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.executeOnLocalNode(OHazelcastPlugin.java:797)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.ODistributedWorker.onMessage(ODistributedWorker.java:296)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.ODistributedWorker.run(ODistributedWorker.java:119)
```

Here is my node code:

```
var document = {.....}  //some object
db.let('document',function(s) {
            s.insert().into(self.tableName).set(document);
        })
        .let('userToDocumentEdge',function(s) {
            s
                .create('edge', 'E')
                .from("#12:19")
                .to('$document');
        })
        .commit()
        .return('$document')
        .one();
```

I have been able to complete other transactions (not with this code above) and #12:19 exists.

We are running ./dserver on a single linux instance.

Any ideas?

Comment: Josh which version of OrientDB?

Comment: OrientDB Server v2.1.2 (build UNKNOWN@r; 2015-09-09 21:41:27+0000)

Comment: The issue was related to first insert failing, one of the properties was an array.   The orient log wasn't appropriately listing that error, just saying the record in the 2nd statement could not be locked.  orientjs was returning a non information error message as well.